# Including recyclerview library in Eclipse project (can't see the library project to include in my project)

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying include v7 recyclerview library in my application project. 
I followed these steps https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library

I imported v7 recyclerview library using *Import Existing Android Code Into Workspace*  and *included* ndroid-support-v7-recyclerview.jar *file to the build path*. 
[image: library project] 
But when I'm trying to include the library to my project after clicking the add button there is no library to include:

From Android developer site: 
Add the library to your application project:

- In the Project Explorer, right-click your project and select Properties.
- In the category panel on the left side of the dialog, select Android.
- In the Library pane, click the Add button.
- Select the library project and click OK. For example, the appcompat project should be listed as android-support-v7-appcompat. **(<- here i don't see the TestActivity)**
- In the properties window, click OK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure the recyclerview library is marked as "Library" in *Project Properties -> Android -> Is Library (checked)*. Once it's marked you will be able to see it in the list when you press *Add* button.